# Отправка гет и пост запросов поставщику запчастей

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста. Хочу попробовать подключиться к веб сервисам поставщика запчастей.
http://www.part-kom.ru/webservices/restv3/search/
Как это сделать проще?

Comment: если вы хотите  просто бросать запросы на апиху и парсить ответы, то я бы использовал ретрофит.

Comment: Для начала возьмите Postman и потренируйтесь с запросами

Comment: Потом создадите веб клиента и отправите запрос